# Question About Morera's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

**Morera's**  Theorem states that a continuous, complex valued function $f$ defined on a connected open set $D$ in the complex plane that satisfies $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz =0$$ for every closed piecewise $C^{1}$ curve $\gamma$ in $D$ must be holomorphic in $D$.

My question is whether this is the minimum hypothesis for $f$ to be holomorphic. I mean, is it necessary that $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$$ should be zero for every closed piecewise $C^1$ curve in $D$ or would some special classes of curve suffice for the same conclusion? This might be an  easy problem but at least I don't have any satisfactory answer. Any reference/ideas?

Comment: yes it is the minimum

Comment: @learnmore do you have a counterexample?

Comment: It is *not* the minimum. It suffices for the integral to vanish on triangles. See the end of the Wikipedia page on Morera's theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can weaken the conditions by only asking the integral to vanish on triangular paths, that is plolygonal curves whit 3 vertices. And of course the proof is more simple than the one of the theorem you state.

The next is taken from the book "Conway: Functions of One Complex Variable I " second edition.

**Theorem 5.10 p.86** Let $G$ be a region and $f:G\to \mathbb{C} $ a continuos function such that 
$$
\int_T f(z) dz =0
$$
for every triangular path $T$ in $G$; then $f$ is analytic in $ G$