# proving analyticity in a region

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem in Rudin's RCA: Suppose that $I=[a,b] $, $\Omega $ is a region, $I\in \Omega$, $f $ continuous in $\Omega $, and $f $ is holomorphic in $\Omega - I $. Prove that actually $f $ is holomorphic in $\Omega $.

I guess I need to prove $f $ is harmonic in $\Omega $.. or is there another suggestion?

Comment: Morera's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @DanielFischer suggestion, by [Morera´s Theorem it suffices to show that for any triangular path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272753/question-about-moreras-theorem/1272882#1272882) $T \subset \Omega$ ($T=\partial \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is a triangle), $\int_T f(z)dz=0$. Take any triangular path $T \subset \Omega$, by Cauchy's Theorem, for any closed path $\gamma \subset \Delta \cap (\Omega \setminus I)$, 
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0
$$
However, this still holds when part of $\gamma$ is in $I$, since $f$ is continuous in $I$. Thus since in the worst case scenario part of $T$ is in $I$, we conlude that indeed $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.